# Should we use webcomponents or not?

Tags: html, web-component

Web development has changed dramatically over the last few years. With the enormous amount of JavaScript libraries and the new HTML5 standard, today it is easier to create rich Internet applications (RIA). When building RIAs, you will probably want to reuse some of the web components you built. But how you can do that with the current state of HTML?

I have starded learning Angular 2, that is based on webcomponents 
http://webcomponents.org/

Only problem i have is that now there is no rule how to write HTML?
http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/

Does it means `<div></div>` will no longer exist?

And HTML can be written as you wish, will be there be some kind of rule, what about HTML5?

Because now you can easy say `<header-layout></header-layout>` and forgot about validation?

Answer (score 0):

Well i just had a discussion over this with our CTO,
Webcomponents is something of the future and too early to say that when we say `<clock></clock>` we will get time displayed on our page and if we say `<clock timeformat='12'> </clock>` boom, we would have a clock in 12hour format. My point here is that it well ahead of the current time.

You could open github and inspect their last commit element and you will see that its a webcomponent. That was the first and the last WebComponent i saw being used on huge scale. here's a link for ref : http://webcomponents.org/articles/interview-with-joshua-peek/

I dont think there are any rules as such for now, like i said its a very future thing.